# use VS Code Python extension to log into remote Jupyter URI that is password-protected (no token in URI)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to use the MS VS Code Python extension to log into a remote JupyterHub server according to these docs, which say to provide the ?token= parameter in the URI:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support

However, the server I'm trying to log into is password protected - I don't really have control over removing the password protection.
The Jupyter docs suggest looking for the token in the jupyter logs, but it looks to me like using password protection suppresses the token from the logs, too:
https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#security-in-the-jupyter-notebook-server

Am I missing something? Is it not possible to use the VS Code extension to log in to a password-protected notebook server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently this is not supported, we only support connecting via the token. We know that this is not optimal for many users, but as of now the only way to enter in the password and authenticate the session is via the actual login HTML page that you see in the browser when you try to connect to a password protected Jupyter. So we don't yet have a way to automate that inside of VSCode. We're looking at adding support for this, but we will probably need changes from the Jupyter side to support this so it won't be in the immediate future.

Comment: Is it supposed to work with an empty token `--NotebookApp.token=` ?
(I know that it's unsafe, but this is done in a closed, safe networking environment)
I tried but got 403.

Comment: That funny. I thought this worked when I checked previously, but I'm seeing the same thing as you. On the server it looks like it is the xsrf check is blocking it. I'm not really saying that I recommend this in general, as it does make things less secure, but just adding --NotebookApp.disable_check_xsrf=True after --NotebookApp.token= got it working for me.

Answer (score 6):

At the moment (31.10.2019) the question is outdated, passwords in jupyter are supported. You are asked for a password on running a first cell.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/commit/e2d536b49d2ef7e1a12cdfb58b752febba5c5048#diff-ccc7e3125787e488d56ae4f73e0f2e18R204